# how to dynamically load the app list in android

Tags: android

Let's say, there are four apps in the system: app1, app2, app3, app4.

Be default, when the system is up, all apps will be shown in the home screen. Now if we provide a customized log in screen, user A log in, then for this user, he can only see (and use ) app1 and app2.

Then A log out, user B log in, he can only see app3 and app4.

Does API provide such capability to load the app list dynamically?

Hope someone can help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends on how you build your logging system. But, in theory,the basisc around applications list in Android system would be something like that :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List pkgAppsList = mContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Comment: thanks. but i still have no idea about how to make a app visible/invisible to the user? and how to do this without restart the device?

I know the manifest file shows if a app can be seen in the home screen, so is there anyway to change this attribute programatically? and after I have change this attribute, how can i update the home screen so some of the app will not be displayed to the user?